# Student with greater average grades by major

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, average, greatest-n-per-group

Tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE major
( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(200)
);

insert into major values 
    (101, 'Computing'), 
    (102, 'Arquitecture');

CREATE TABLE student
( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(200), 
    major_id INT,
    foreign key(major_id) references major(id)
);

insert into student  values
    (1001, 'Claude', 101),
    (1002, 'John', 101),
    (1003, 'Peter', 102);

CREATE TABLE course
( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(200)
);

insert into course values 
    (901, 'Databases'), 
    (902, 'Java'),
    (903, 'Artificial Intelligence'), 
    (904, 'OOP');
    
CREATE TABLE grades
(
   student_id INT,
   course_id INT,
   grade integer,
   primary key (student_id, course_id),
   foreign key(student_id) references student(id),
   foreign key(course_id) references course(id)
);

insert into grades  values
    (1001, 903, 95),
    (1001, 904, 88),
    (1002, 901, 76),
    (1002, 903, 82),
    (1003, 902, 87);
```

Expected:

```
| student    | major        | grade |
| ---------- | -------------| ----- |
| Peter      | Architecture | 87    |
| Claude     | Computing    | 91.5  |
```

In other words: retrieve top grade student for each major.

Playground [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/2).

If possible, without TOP,LIMIT.

If possible old ANSI SQL as well as using window functions.

Engine MySQL, but not required.

My approach [#1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/0):

```
-- average grade by student
select s.name as Student,  m.name as Major, avg(g.grade) as Average
         from student s
         inner join grades g on (s.id = g.student_id)
         inner join major m on (m.id = s.major_id)
         group by s.id
```

but John is not needed:

```
| Student | Major        | Average |
| ------- | ------------ | ------- |
| Claude  | Computing    | 91.5000 |
| John    | Computing    | 79.0000 |
| Peter   | Arquitecture | 87.0000 |
```

My approach [#2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/1):

```
-- Max average grade by career; lacks student
select a.major, max (a.average) as Average
    from (select s.name as Student,  m.name as Major, avg(g.grade) as average
         from student s
         inner join grades g on (s.id = g.student_id)
         inner join major m on (m.id = s.major_id)
         group by s.id) a
    group by a.major;
```

but lacks student column.

```
| major        | Average |
| ------------ | ------- |
| Arquitecture | 87.0000 |
| Computing    | 91.5000 |
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the criteria to exclude John?

Comment: @ntalbs John is studyng computing but Cluade has greater average grade. Must group by major then choose the student with greater average, something like max(avg(grade)).

Comment: So, do you want to retrieve top grade student for each major?

Comment: That't right. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select s.name as student, m.name as major, avg(g.grade) as average,
        rank() over(partition by m.id order by avg(g.grade) desc) rn
    from student s
    inner join grades g on s.id = g.student_id
    inner join major m on  m.id = s.major_id
    group by s.id, m.id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Notes:

- `rank()` allows ties
- parentheses around the join conditions are superfluous

Comment: What if Claude and John had the same average grade? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/7

Comment: @AntonioSánchez:  as I said, *rank() allows ties*, so it gives both Claude and John. Which result do you want?

Comment: Select just any of them, as if Student info was irrelevant and the query was "greater average grades by career", no matter which student.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez: if so, use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine your two queries:

```
select a.* FROM 
(        select s.name as Student, m.name as Major, avg(g.grade) as Average
         from student s
         inner join grades g on (s.id = g.student_id)
         inner join major m on (m.id = s.major_id)
         group by s.id
) a
INNER JOIN 
(select a.major, max (a.average) as Average
    from (select s.name as Student,  m.name as Major, avg(g.grade) as average
         from student s
         inner join grades g on (s.id = g.student_id)
         inner join major m on (m.id = s.major_id)
         group by s.id) a
    group by a.major   ) b
ON a.major=b.major and a.average=b.average
```

Comment: In general, all non-aggregated columns in a SELECT clause MUST be included in a GROUP BY clause - although I accept the premise that a student can only have one major.

Comment: What if Claude and John had the same average grade? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/6

Comment: Then you either need to use top or switch to window functions.
GMB already provided an answer using window functions https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cABESz8puGeFSfGfAytPtu/0

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of MySQL...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM
     ( SELECT m.name major
            , s.name student
            , AVG(grade) avg_grade
         FROM major m
         JOIN student s
           ON s.major_id = m.id
         JOIN grades g
           ON g.student_id = s.id
        GROUP
           BY major
            , student
     ) x
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT major
            , MAX(avg_grade) avg_grade
         FROM 
            ( SELECT m.name major
                   , s.name student
                   , AVG(grade) avg_grade
                FROM major m
                JOIN student s
                  ON s.major_id = m.id
                JOIN grades g
                  ON g.student_id = s.id
               GROUP
                  BY major
                   , student
            )n
        GROUP
           BY major
      ) y
     ON y.major = x.major
    AND y.avg_grade = x.avg_grade

| major        | student | avg_grade |
| ------------ | ------- | --------- |
| Arquitecture | Peter   | 87.0000   |
| Computing    | Claude  | 91.5000   |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/5)

Comment: What if Claude and John had the same average grade? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mr4GRz5tJ3ofFeQcTZvF8/8

Comment: @AntonioSánchez What would you expect to happen in this circumstance?

Comment: Select just any of them, as if Student info was irrelevant and the query was "greater average grades by career", no matter which student.

Comment: Well, this does that! :-)